# What is the difference between standard angular and angular + ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to understand the difference between a standard angular 4 build vs using angular + ngrx?

Comment: `ngrx` is a reactive library framework that adds provides `redux` look and feel to your components.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Are you specificaly talking about ngrx store when you say ngrx?

If so, it's an implementation of Redux specifically for Angular. It might be worth reading through the [Redux introduction](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Motivation.html) to get an idea about what it's all about.

Generally, it's a pattern for controlling the state of an application, and the flow of data throughout the appliction.

Take, for example, an angular component. The component `MyComponent` loads some data "products". Now, whenever you navagate away from this, as this data (state) it's stored in the `MyComponent` it's lost. So we're always reloading it whenever the component is created. Not very efficient, and not great for our impatient user.

And maybe `MyOtherComponent` also gets the products! It holds it's list of products. But users can edit the `product.name` here. The state has been modified by `MyOtherComponent`, without `MyComponent` knowing about it - so it's still displaying the old name. We could have each hold a reference to the other, or have the parent get the data - but that's starting to [closely couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) all our components in a big web. Not good news if we ever want to change anything.

A solution is to inject a service, `MyProductsService` that deals with things to do (let's call them actions?) like `loadData()`, and stores that state in a central location.

Now, when someone needs it, they ask `MyProductsService` for it, and it loads it and provides the data. When someone modifies it they have to go back to `MyProductsService`, and it can then... ah. See, how does `MyProductService` tell it's dependencies that someone's changed the state? `MyProductsService.products` has been updated, but it needs to "push" that change to both `MyComponent` and `MyOtherComponent`.

Here's where NgRx (RxJS designed for Angular) is useful. It uses the [Observable Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to manage "pushing" data. When someone want's `products`, it's provided as an Observable, and the `MyComponents` subscribe to updates. When it changes, the `products` observable emits a new value and everyone's happy.

Now, after all this is over you'll have ended up creating something that's starting to look a little like Redux, but it's custom - probably has bugs, untested and you've spent hours and hours on it.

So you can always use the version already written by really clever people and thoroughly tested with helpful tutorials. It follows the best practices, genearlly. The way of interacting with it (mutating state) is very strict, so it prevents unwanted side-effects. The data 'flows' down from the top in a predictable, testable and repeatable way.

Comment: _"Here enters RxJs (or NgRx for Angular)."_.  This sounds like ngrx is angular version of rxjs , which is not.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking "here's where you need RxJS - or if you're using angular, NgRx" but my wording was terrible. Edited.